# Creating a dictionary that keeps track of the count of the number of items in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a python newbie and im trying to use a dictionary to count the number of items in x.

```
x = [1,2,1,4,3,2,5,9]

def counts(my_list):
    counts = dict()
    for item in my_list:
        counts[x] = counts.get(item,0)+1

    return counts

counts(x)
```

Any help that makes this work would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `counts[item] = counts.get(item,0)+1`

Comment: @coldspeed That worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: So there is a typo in the question, `x` is not defined in `counts()` thus the problem happens because of this( referring the comment that fixes it). What is the site policy on typo questions ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a default value 0 using `counts.setdefault(item, 0)` and then increment with `counts[item] += 1` for each item.

You can also used the `collections.Counter` class, that does just that.

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(your_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find each element count in the list. Below solution will be helpful.

```
x = [1,2,1,4,3,2,5,9]

def counts(my_list):
    item_count = {}
    for item in my_list:
        item_count[item] = item_count.get(item,0)+1

    return counts

counts(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

```
def counts(my_list):
    counts= {}
    for item in x:
        counts[item] = x.count(item)
    return counts

print(counts(x))
```

Or have fun with it and :

```
def counts(my_list):
    counts = {item: x.count(item) for item in x}
    return counts

print(counts(x))
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 list_dict.py 
> {1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 9: 1}
> ```